# Adding an id_rsa key broke my ssh connexion

Tags: ssh

Today, I've started to setup a gitolite server on my ubuntu 10.04 server, and I needed to generate a public/private key pair with ssh-keygen.

So far no problem. I've generated the 2 files (id_rsa & id_rsa.pub ) without any trouble on my Ubuntu 10.10 client, then transfered (copied) the id_rsa.pub key to the server ( in /tmp/ ) for installing the gitolite server.

But next, when I wanted to get connected by SSH to the server from the client, I was receiving an error that was looking something like:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Searching google, the answer I found were related to /etc/fstab. That kind of makes no sense in my case. I've then got the idea to remove the ~/.ssh/id_rsa and id_rsa.pub key from my client, and I was again able to establish a SSH connection.

Ca someone explain why that happenned ?
I feel like I don't understand something about authentication keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitolite sets up the authorized_keys file in such a way where you wouldn't have shell access to the server.  There's a few ways around this:

1. You can setup a password to log into the machine, and not use your SSH key except when you are using git.
2. You can generate another SSH key to use to administrate the machine, this would require you use ssh -i to override the default key that is provided when logging in.  If you choose this route, add your key *manually* (don't use gitolite), and make sure your key appears before any added by gitolite.

Basically, what happened is by design.  Gitolite does not allow any user to get shell access to the server, so the (somewhat confusing) error message just indicates it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for that message is that the server has maxed out the number of available terminals, because too many users are connected at once. This would be a transient failure, as users connecting and disconnecting would saturate and desaturate the number of ptys.

Another possible reason, probably the one that applies to you, is that keys can be restricted to forbid terminal allocation. This isn't terribly useful in most cases, but makes sense for a server that's only allowing storage and not general use — for example git storage. If the key has the `no-pty` flag (check the corresponding line in [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT)), you won't be able to log in with a terminal.

If you're an administrator on a git server, you'll probably want to have a key without restrictions. Just run `ssh-keygen` without `-O` and `ssh-copy-id` to install a key without restrictions. Use restricted keys for ordinary users who run nothing but git on the server.

Answer (score 0):

That error does not look like a key problem, something else is likely broken with your ssh server configs. Have you restarted sshd on the server? Are you able to login from a console? How about sshing from another machine?

Comment: Nop, I never toutched the server SSH config. I don't have physical access to the server ( and it's a virtual machine ). As far as I know, SSH connection work great from everywhere.

Comment: "As far as I know" doesn't help debug a situation like this. You really need to TRY to ssh in from another machine to see if you really have a working ssh server or not. The error above doesn't look like a key problem, so if it isn't your server you have some other client configuration issue.

Comment: Let me the time to get back to my job -- and try it, it's the weekend ! ;)